# Using a class that is both Observable and Codable in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a clone of game for educational purposes (Wordle) and it is important that closing the app doesn't reset the game's project, moe importantly the game itself. I've implemented how it would work if it was just codable, and some extra classes to get rid of errors. I believe the issue lies in not implementing properly for both of these situations together.

The view gets loaded from the menu with the function

```
WordleView().environmentObject(WordleDataModel.loadData())
```

This is what the data model has for my implementation (based on a successful implementation of a class that was exclusively codable):

```
class WordleDataModel: ObservableObject, Codable{
    @Published var guesses: [Guess] = []
    @Published var incorrectAttempts = [Int](repeating: 0,count: 6)
    @Published var toastText: String?
    @Published var showStats = false
    
    @Published var currentStat: WordleStatistic
    
    var keyColors = [String : String]()
    var matchedLetters = [String]()
    var misplacedLetters = [String]()
    var selectedWord = ""
    var currentWord = ""
    var tryIndex = 0
    var inPlay = false
    var gameOver = false
    var toastWords = ["Genius", "Magnificent", "Impressive", "Splendid", "Great", "Phew"]
    
    var gameStarted: Bool {...}
    
    var disabledKeys: Bool {...}
    
    init() {
        currentStat = WordleStatistic.loadStat()
        newGame()
    }
    
    func saveData() {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "WordleData")
        }
    }
    
    static func loadData() -> WordleDataModel {
        if let savedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "WordleData") as? Data {
            if let currentData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WordleDataModel.self, from: savedData){
                return currentData
            }
            else{
                return WordleDataModel()
            }
        } else {
            return WordleDataModel()
        }
    }
    
    func newGame() {
        populateDefaults()
        selectedWord = Global.commonWords.randomElement()!
        currentWord = ""
        inPlay = true
        tryIndex = 0
        gameOver = false
        print("Selected Word Is: ", selectedWord)
        
        saveData()
    }
    
    func populateDefaults() {...}
    
    ....more game functions....
    }
```

I would assume that if a game has never been created it would initialize it normally, in all other cases it would use data saved in `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "WordleData")`, then if I wanted to create a new game I would simply need to run the `newGame()`. This is for th purpose that if someone closes the app fully and opens it again it should retain and show all previous game information.

It just doesn't work like that though, it always creates a new game after closing the app and opening it back up. I've tried adding print statements into the loadData() and even when a new game is created those prints do not show making it more difficult to know where the issue lies. I'm also calling the saveData() function every time the enter button is hit.

Also the only way to allow this class to run was to add:

```
enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case guesses, incorrectAttempts,toastText,showStats,currentStat, keyColors, matchedLetters, misplacedLetters, selectedWord, currentWord, tryIndex, inPlay, gameOver
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(guesses, forKey: .guesses)
        try container.encode(incorrectAttempts, forKey: .incorrectAttempts)
        
        try container.encode(toastText, forKey: .toastText)
        try container.encode(showStats, forKey: .showStats)
        try container.encode(currentStat, forKey: .currentStat)
        
        try container.encode(keyColors, forKey: .keyColors)
        try container.encode(matchedLetters, forKey: .matchedLetters)
        try container.encode(misplacedLetters, forKey: .misplacedLetters)
        try container.encode(selectedWord, forKey: .selectedWord)
        try container.encode(currentWord, forKey: .currentWord)
        try container.encode(tryIndex, forKey: .tryIndex)
        try container.encode(inPlay, forKey: .inPlay)
        try container.encode(gameOver, forKey: .gameOver)
        
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        guesses = try container.decode([Guess].self, forKey: .guesses)
        incorrectAttempts = try container.decode([Int].self, forKey: .incorrectAttempts)
        
        toastText = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .toastText)
        showStats = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .showStats)
        currentStat = try container.decode(WordleStatistic.self, forKey: .currentStat)
        
        keyColors = try container.decode([String : String].self, forKey: .keyColors)
        matchedLetters = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .matchedLetters)
        misplacedLetters = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .misplacedLetters)
        selectedWord = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .selectedWord)
        currentWord = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .currentWord)
        tryIndex = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .tryIndex)
        inPlay = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .inPlay)
        gameOver = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .gameOver)
    }
```

I'm not really using these at all except to get rid of errors. When I research the topic it never goes any further explaing how to implement these functions properly people just say to add it.

I have absolutly no errors but closing the app and reopening does not repopulate the game as it should. In over 5 years I've never posted here before but I'm struggling quite a bit getting over this hurdle, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Where and how are you calling the saveData and loadData functions?

Comment: Looks like a lot of potentially odd stuff here. Why are you using `AnyView`? Your model should be a `struct`; then, Coddle will work easily since the `@Published` property wrappers won't get in the way. You can still use an `ObservableObject` to load/save those entities (although you don't _need_ to)

Comment: I have an array of games (with game class) where one parameter is a link to the view so it can dynamically be attached to a button in the menu. The only way I was able to store views in a class that was generalized was with AnyView. @jnpdx

Comment: When I call the view it uses the loadData function in the environment object parameter, when a new game is created (newGame function) or the enter button is pushed (for playing the wordle game) it will also call saveData. @ElTomato

Comment: You should watch Demystify SwiftUI re: AnyView. Plus, you shouldn't be "storing views"

Comment: Ok that's very good to know so I'll adjust that, and I'll also check out the video thanks.

Comment: Now whenever the button is pressed to go to the view it always generates a new game i.e. in loadData() it never gets the decoded data and always returns a new WordleDataModel. The saveData function does run and the views now seem to be going to one another properly but any idea why it never returns with the decoded data @jnpdx

Comment: You're using `try?` instead of `do/try/catch`, so you're just throwing away errors. Print the real error. And, like I suggested, don't try to use your own Codable conformance. Make your model a struct and use the synthesized conformance.

Comment: Just FYI Observable is the replacement for ObservableObject they are not equivalent.